# The expected value of this question keeps telling me this is wrong

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I'm new to Python and programming in general so have mercy on my soul please. The question is:

Write code to assign the string "You can apply to SI!" to output if the string "SI 106" is in the list courses. If it is not in courses, assign the value "Take SI 106!" to the variable output.

```
courses = ["ENGR 101", "SI 110", "ENG 125", "SI 106", "CHEM 130"]

if "SI 106" == courses:
    output = "You can apply to SI"
else: 
    output = "Take SI 106"
```

It tells me i failed. It should be "Take SI 106".

Did i make a mistake? "SI 106" is in the list so the output should be "You can apply to SI", no?

Comment: You want `'SI 106' in courses`. `==` checks for equality, and a `str` does not equal a `list`

Comment: Instead of `"SI 106" == courses`, which is an equality check, you should use `"SI 106" in courses`, which looks up if the item `"SI 106"` is in the list `courses`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the keyword `in`.

You code should look like this (without the comment)

```
courses = ["ENGR 101", "SI 110", "ENG 125", "SI 106", "CHEM 130"]

if "SI 106" in courses:
    #       ^^
    output = "You can apply to SI"
else: 
    output = "Take SI 106"
```

Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_in.asp) for reference

Comment: I have promptly facepalmed myself lol. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

```py
courses = ["ENGR 101", "SI 110", "ENG 125", "SI 106", "CHEM 130"]

if "SI 106" in courses:
    output = "You can apply to SI!"
else:
    output = "Take SI 106"
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged for not spelling out how the proposed code is an answer. I fail to see what your answer adds to ozerodb's.